# Creating an AS3 game using the Platogo engine

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I just started to learn AS3 and decided to use the Platogo engine, and I got stuck on the first part. It is described as follows:

> Connect your game with Platogo
>
> Your game must successfully connect to
>   Platogo before any function of the
>   Platogo API can be used. The following
>   code sample shows how to call 
>   `PlatogoAPI.connect()` . You need to
>   pass the  game ID  from the Edit Game
>   page, your game's root and a callback
>   function. The callback is invoked once
>   the connection has been established.
>   From this point on you can continue
>   with your normal game logic.

```
import com.platogo.api.PlatogoAPI;
import com.platogo.api.enums.PlatogoStatus;
import com.platogo.api.vo.PlatogoResponse;

PlatogoAPI.connect( [your game id], [reference to stage], connectHandler );

function connectHandler( response : PlatogoResponse ) : void
{
    if( response.status == PlatogoStatus.OK )
    {
    trace("You are now connected to Platogo & the API is ready to be used.");
    }
}
```

Where do I need to paste this code to? A new AS file or in my game's existing ActionScript code? and in which section?

Do I still need to keep the square bracket after substitute my id game into [your game id] and what does [reference to stage] mean?

(could you teach me how to work with normal Flash engine, too?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might sound rude but, I think you'd be better off to learn some basic AS3 before trying to hook up to some third-party-api.

Your questions then:

The part '[your game id]' would entirely be substituted by the API key I presume you received somewhere. The parameter [reference to stage] would also be substituted by a reference to the stage object, in Flash Pro you're probably safe to pass in something like this `this.stage`.

Your call to PlagotoAPI.connect might look something like this: `PlatogoAPI.connect(12345, this.stage, connectHandler);`

Comment: Yeah, that's a little bit, but fine to me, since i'm very rush.

Comment: but Thank you, anyway, for your help and it means a lot to me ^^